# Farseer acceleration with Gravity help?

Tags: c#, forms, farseer

I am new to the Farseer library and I am attempting to make a C# forms application using Farseer.  I have created a form, placed a floor on the form and I am dropping a single rectangle from the top of the form to the bottom.  The block appears to fall BUT it does not accelerate with the gravity.  I am sure it is something I am not setting, but for the life of me I cant figure it out and was hoping someone might point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for the help,

Jeff

==============================Important CODE=================================

```
 World world = new World(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.1f));

//Floor
Body floor = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 10000.0f, 30.0f, 100, new Vector2(0.0f, Height));
floor.BodyType = BodyType.Static;

// Block
 Body Block1 = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 100.0f, 10.0f, 100, new Vector2(Width/2, 0));
 Block1.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;

//(The step here is called when I timer goes off every .01/second)
 //Step the world a 10th of a second.
 world.Step((float).01f);



//(I draw the object this way)

 gr.TranslateTransform(body.Position.X, body.Position.Y);
 gr.RotateTransform((float)((body.Rotation *360)/(2*Math.PI)));
 gr.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.ButtonFace, -size.Width / 2.0f, -size.Height / 2.0f, size.Width, size.Height);  
 gr.ResetTransform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out!  The problem was that I was using Pixel instead of meters, once I figured that out you can now see the gravity take effect on the falling block.  Sorry for the noise.

Taken for the FAQ:

What units does Box2D use?¶

Box2D is tuned for meters-kilograms-seconds (MKS). Your moving objects should be between 0.1 - 10 meters. Do not use pixels as units! You will get a jittery simulation.

How do I convert pixels to meters?

Suppose you have a sprite for a character that is 100x100 pixels. You decide to use a scaling factor that is 0.01. This will make the character physics box 1m x 1m. So go make a physics box that is 1x1. Now suppose the character starts out at pixel coordinate (345,679). So position the physics box at (3.45,6.79). Now simulate the physics world. Suppose the character physics box moves to (2.31,4.98), so move your character sprite to pixel coordinates (231,498). Now the only tricky part is choosing a scaling factor. This really depends on your game. You should try to get your moving objects in the range 0.1 - 10 meters, with 1 meter being the sweet spot.